# Is it possible to duplicate a publication?

Tags: sql-server, database-replication

We have several separate databases which have the same schema but different data. One of them takes part in replication but the others currently don't.

If we want to add publications to more databases, they'd be exactly the same as the first one, except that they'd be for a different database and have different subscribers. Is it possible in any way to create a publication for DatabaseB based on the publication for DatabaseA, rather than go through the steps of setting it up from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script out the publication and then edit it for the new database.

Then run it in the new database.

Comment: Thanks. We've done that but there seems to be a problem that we don't yet know is or isn't related to this, so I'll choose an answer after it's resolved.

Comment: The problem was unrelated, the above worked like a charm. Although I should add that the last few sections of the script (related to the subscribers) should be deleted.